# Javascript download source video but canot open it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension who need to download video from a source website. And i have created this code

```
fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          // Create a temporary link element
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.download = fileName;
          link.type = 'video/mp4'; // Set the MIME type explicitly
  
          // Trigger the download
          link.click();
  
          // Clean up
          URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error downloading the video:', error);
        });
```

This run inside a `downloadVideo(some parameters)` function. And this function really download each video i click the download button, but there is another problem: Some videos are not opening from my player. Some video open but let say if i download 20 video only 2 - 3 open from player. Others show me this error [image]

Comment: Just looking at the error, it looks like the file name is incorrect. It's not clear from the code you provided where the `fileName` comes from, but for example in that error, the file name appears to be `The squaddd    #lowglow #stance #cars #jdm .mp4`, which may be a valid name for the video on a website (a title with various hashtags), but that's most likely not a valid file url. If you want to use the video title as the file name you probably just need to sanitize the text to remove illegal characters.

Comment: The problem is caused by the contents of the file, which means `url` is incorrect or the data is protected by a token, which is already expired, or it's a blob: URL that was already revoked by the site. The file name is not a problem as all the characters shown in the error are valid.

Comment: Yes, you are right the data are protecterd by a token. But is there any way i can download this source video ? i am trying to download from  tiktok